# scala: How can I pass a 0-arg function somewhere without calling it?

Tags: scala

```
def myfunc():Int = 10
class FuncUser( val func:()=>Int )
val i = new FuncUser( myfunc )
```

This fails because myfunc is immediately evaluated -- its type is Int, not ()=>Int
How can directly pass myfunc to the FuncUser constructor?

Also, this works:

```
val y4:()=>Int = myfunc
val j = new FuncUser( y4 )
```

but I'm confused about why the first line succeeds? Why isn't myfunc also immediately evaluated in this second example?

Comment: Your first example works fine for me (using scala 2.10.3).

Comment: Using:   Scala IDE for Eclipse 3.0.2.v-2_10-201310181157-0880865 org.scala-ide.sdt.feature.feature.group scala-ide.org . So maybe on older version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use partial application to "lift" the *method* (it's not a true function) `myfunc` to a `Function0`:

```
val i = new FuncUser(myfunc _)
```

Comment: By the spec, it is a function, and what we call function is an _anonymous function_.

Comment: When you write `def thing ...` the Scala compiler creates a method in some class, be it anonymous or otherwise. Such entities are *not* first-class functions in the sense that true functions are values with types that may be passed around and *applied* to arguments. It does us no good to conflate disparate entities just 'cause they're superficially similar.

Comment: I'm not conflating anything, it's just what the spec call a `def`: a function. It has a _method_ type, whereas _anonymous_ functions (the spec name for first class functions) have _function_ types.